# chai test array equality doesn't work as expected

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

Why does the following fail?

```
expect([0,0]).to.equal([0,0]);
```

and what is the right way to test that?

Answer (score 427, accepted):

For **expect**, `.equal` will compare objects rather than their data, and in your case it is two different arrays.

Use `.eql` in order to deeply compare values. Check out this [link](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_arguments).
Or you could use `.deep.equal` in order to simulate same as `.eql`.
Or in your case you might want to [check](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_members) `.members`.

For **asserts** you can use `.deepEqual`, [link](https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_notstrictequal).

Comment: FTR, the deep equal syntax has changed to: `.deepEqual()` (http://chaijs.com/api/assert).

Comment: It is not changed, you are looking at **Asserts** functionality, but not **Expect/Should** which topic starter was concerned about.

Comment: You're right, I didn't read well. I thought it's just another API change.

Comment: `to.deep.equal(['a','b'])` does not seem to work. however `to.have.all.members(['a','b'])` does. so cumbersome…

Comment: https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/deep-equal-in-any-order/ worked well when the order of object attributes was unpredictable.

Answer (score 77):

Try to use deep Equal. It will compare nested arrays as well as nested Json.

```
expect({ foo: 'bar' }).to.deep.equal({ foo: 'bar' });
```

Please refer to [main documentation site](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/).

Comment: This also works for arrays: `expect([1, 5, 10].sort()).to.deep.equal([1, 10, 5])`

Answer (score 3):

for unordered deep equality, use *members*

`expect([1,2,3]).to.have.members([3,2,1]); // passes expect([1,2,3]).to.have.members([1,2,3]); // passes  expect([1,2,3]).to.eql([3,2,1]); // fails`

[source](https://medium.com/building-ibotta/testing-arrays-and-objects-with-chai-js-4b372310fe6d)

Answer (score 1):

```js
import chai from 'chai';
const arr1 = [2, 1];
const arr2 = [2, 1];
chai.expect(arr1).to.eql(arr2); // Will pass. `eql` is data compare instead of object compare.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.deepEqual()`

```
const { assert } = require('chai');

assert.deepEqual([0,0], [0,0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_samedeepmembers

```
assert.sameDeepMembers(set1, set2, [message])
```

Asserts that `set1` and `set2` have the same members in any order. Uses a deep equality check.

```
assert.sameDeepMembers([ { a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 } ], [{ b: 2 }, { a: 1 }, { c: 3 }], 'same deep members');
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how to use chai to deeply test associative arrays.

I had an issue trying to assert that two *associative* arrays were equal. I know that these shouldn't really be used in javascript but I was writing unit tests around legacy code which returns a reference to an associative array. :-)

I did it by defining the variable as an object (not array) prior to my function call:

```
var myAssocArray = {};   // not []
var expectedAssocArray = {};  // not []

expectedAssocArray['myKey'] = 'something';
expectedAssocArray['differentKey'] = 'something else';

// legacy function which returns associate array reference
myFunction(myAssocArray);

assert.deepEqual(myAssocArray, expectedAssocArray,'compare two associative arrays');
```