# immutable update returns the same value but it seems to be of different format/type

Tags: reactjs, immutability

I'm trying to make an inventory system and I would like to add an Item so I made a muck up code to see how update works and I keep on getting errors on the assertion. so I used an IF ELSE statement to compare and log the result and they I always get NOT EQUAL even tho the update result(state2) is just the same as expected(state3).

```
const state1 = ['x','y'];
const state2 = update(state1, {$push: ['z']});
const state3 = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

expect(state2).to.equal(state3);

//log results
if (state2 === state3) {
    console.log("EQUAL!!! state2 = " + state2 + ", state3 = " + state3);
} else {
    console.log("NOT EQUAL!!! state2 = " + state2 + ", state3 = " + state3);
}
```

the assertion error I get is:

```
AssertionError: expected [ 'x', 'y', 'z' ] to equal [ 'x', 'y', 'z' ]
```

Comment: Use `eql`, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526805/chai-test-array-equality-doesnt-work-as-expected

Comment: They are different, so use `to.eql` or `to.deep.equal`

Comment: exactly what I need! thanks!!!