# How to test the function correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing

I have a function that makes an `API` request and receives data in `json` format.

```
async function getDataAboutWeather(url) {
    return await new Promise(resolve => {
        request(url, (err, res, body) => {
            if (err) {
                throw new Error(err);
            };
            const info = JSON.parse(body);
            resolve(info);
        });
    });
};
```

I want to write a test for this function.

```
describe('getDataAboutWeather function', () => {
    it('The request should success', () => {
        const link = 'http://ip.jsontest.com';
        expect(getDataAboutWeather(link)).to.eql({});
    });
});
```

How to verify that my function works as it should?

Since at the moment I get an error.

```
AssertionError: expected {} to deeply equal {}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [chai test array equality doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526805/chai-test-array-equality-doesnt-work-as-expected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getDataAboutWeather is an asynchronous function which means it returns a Promise. I would change the test to:

```
it('The request should success', async () => {
        const link = 'http://ip.jsontest.com';
        expect(await getDataAboutWeather(link)).to.eql({});
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

To test your function, you need to check if the API JSON is equal to the expected JSON. You can use the function below.

```
_.isEqual(object, other);
```

More information on this: [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)